# How do I maintain referential integrity on a variable list of foreign keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-modeling

How do I maintain referential integrity on a variable list of foreign keys? How do I model my data appropriately to achieve such a thing?

Suppose there is a `subject` and `teacher` tables that store the information about both respectively.

```sql
CREATE TABLE subject (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    name text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    description text
);
CREATE TABLE teacher (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    full_name text NOT NULL
)
```

There is also a junction table `teacher_subject`, to show which teachers teach which subjects and vice-versa.

```sql
CREATE TABLE teacher_subject(
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    teacher_id bigint NOT NULL,
    subject_id bigint NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(teacher_id, subject_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (teacher_id) REFERENCES teacher (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subject (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Let's imagine that a student can submit a request to study a subject. As a part of the application, they select a subject from a dropdown box, and all the teachers teaching it show up. Each one of the teachers has a checkbox next to their name. The student can then deselect the teacher's name to mark that they don't want to be in a class with that particular teacher. Let's say I want to store this application request in a table called `subject_application`. How exactly do I store the list of teachers that the student found acceptable while maintaining referential integrity with respect to both the `teacher` table and `teacher_subject` table that stores the link between subject and teacher?

I tried thinking about, perhaps there can be a foreign key array, like described [here](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/17/1252/) but it seems that this proposal isn't going anywhere. I then thought that perhaps I could have something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE subject_application (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    student_id bigint NOT NULL,
    subject_id bigint NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(student_id, subject_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subject (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE preferred_teachers (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    teacher_id bigint NOT NULL,
    subject_application_id bigint NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(teacher_id, subject_application_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (teacher_id) REFERENCES teacher (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (subject_application_id) REFERENCES subject_application (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Where the subject being applied to and the student applying would be stored in the `subject_application` junction table, while the corresponding teacher preferences would be stored in the `preferred_teachers` table. The only trouble is that referential integrity isn't necessarily maintained with respect to `teacher_subject`. I could absolutely write a row in `preferred_teachers` that references a teacher who doesn't teach the subject referenced in the `subject_application`. Of course, I could always write triggers to ensure referential integrity, but I was wondering if it was possible to come up with a purely SQL solution to this data modelling problem.

### EDIT:

As per [Adrian Klaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver)'s comment, in `preferred_teachers` I tried to point at `id` of `teacher_subject` (presumably instead of `teacher`) as it encapsulates the **TEACHER <-> SUBJECT** relationship. So it looks like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE subject_application (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    student_id bigint NOT NULL,
    subject_id bigint NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(student_id, subject_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subject (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE preferred_teachers (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    teacher_subject_id bigint NOT NULL,
    subject_application_id bigint NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(teacher_subject_id, subject_application_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (teacher_subject_id) REFERENCES teacher_subject (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (subject_application_id) REFERENCES subject_application (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

But I could still imagine writing a row in `preferred_teachers` where it references a subject application for **PHYSICS**, and yet the `teacher_subject_id` points to a **MATH <-> SOME TEACHER** row.
I also considered removing `subject_id` from `subject_application` and relying on `preferred_teachers` to hold the information about both the preferred teachers and the subject.

```sql
CREATE TABLE subject_application (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    student_id bigint NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE preferred_teachers (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    teacher_subject_id bigint NOT NULL,
    subject_application_id bigint NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(teacher_subject_id, subject_application_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (teacher_subject_id) REFERENCES teacher_subject (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (subject_application_id) REFERENCES subject_application (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

However, I am now not sure how to enforce that there must only be one subject per application (as I could easily insert references for both **MATH <-> SOME TEACHER** and **PHYSICS <-> SOME OTHER TEACHER** for the same application), and that there must only be maximum one application per subject, per student (as I can now create one application that references the row **MATH <-> SOME TEACHER** and another application that references **MATHS <-> SOME OTHER TEACHER**).

Comment: In `preferred_teachers` point at `id` of `teacher_subject`.  The teacher -> subject relationship is spelled out there.

Comment: would i point to `teacher_subject` instead of just `teacher`? because I could imagine pointing to a `MATH <-> MR ROBERTS` row in `teacher_subject`, while also pointing to a `SOME STUDENT <-> COMPUTER SCIENCE` row in `subject_application`, so now there is a lack of referential integrity with regards to the subject being applied to and the subject-teacher relationship that is referenced. or do you mean something different?

Comment: Hmm, you are looking for a conditional FK. That is not possible. Your choices are 1) Let the front end take care of presenting only valid choices to the student. 2) Add a trigger to `preferred_teachers` that screens the incoming rows.

Comment: Your edit is great, but the what-ifs you list after roam into absurdity territory.
 You have to trust your code to do the correct thing at some point.  The model @AdrianKlaver helped you create captures the majority of brain-dead mistakes that are dead simple for FK integrity checks to catch.  I realize that the failure modes you then list would be difficult to detect and fix if they happen, but you have to ask yourself whether it is reasonable to waste time and energy on those corner cases that could be better spent hardening your schema against a catastrophic meteor impact, instead.

Comment: @MikeOrganek Right I see. so even though there might be a theoretical solution to make invalid states impossible to represent, chasing it is not worth it. I have to just write a few insert/update triggers and move on. Understood.

Comment: I would suggest an application table, an application_subject intersection table and an application_subject_preferredteacher intersection table. A UK on the 2 FKs in the intersection table ensures duplicates can’t be selected and only teachers who teach the subject can be set as preferred as these are the only teachers you make available in the UI of the application (using a separate teacher/subject intersection table)

Comment: "*As a part of the application, they select a subject from a dropdown box, and all the teachers teaching it show up.*" so how would a user choose physics & teacher-a then you end-up with math & teacher-a?  Are you conflating the isse of changing teacher/course combination (a school admin task) with students choosing their preferences. Don't combine those issues - treat them separately. If there are emergency change to physics/teacher-a (e.g. teacher is ill)  deactivate those preferences and notify the affected students. (assuming the app has notification capability)

Comment: @PaulMaxwell I wans't thinking about it wholistically, with the UI + backend + DB as a single unit. I was rather thinking from the perspective of the DB itself, like it is not aware of anything other than itself, how to make invalid states unrepresentable within the DB itself. So that it doesn't have any coupling to the UI - relying on it for verification. But as the other comments pointed out, that would be a waste of time to chase, even if its theoretically possible to achieve such a design.